# Magento2 installation in Ubuntu 500 internal error

Tags: apache2, php

Im using apache2 and php7.

Im trying to install the Magento2.

But when i hit the server 10.20. ... i get 500 Internal server error..

Checks i made:

1) Gave 0777 to all folders

2) there is no .htaccess file in root folder

3) Cloned magento 2 from github in the following folder /var/www/html/magento2/

4) ran composer install.

Works perfect in windows, whats missing in Linux as im installing for the 1st time in Ubuntu

Comment: Gave 0777 to all folders basically means 'Gave access to random people on the Internet to my web site'. Just don't do it. Never ever!

Comment: Ok , path and permission was the problem, fixed now, thanks! and no my server is not hosted @oerdnj, its kept for developing purpose

Comment: @SachinS Same issue. How did you exactly solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow link below , followed the same it works correctly.
[7 Steps to Install Magento 2 on Ubuntu/Debian [Latest] - Sample Data](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-install-magento-2-ubuntu.html)

Also you have to create apache user on system to run php bin/magento command

Comment: Include steps from link you've given because of link could became unavailable and give a reference to resource you've taken info from.